# Google Analytics: not receiving two data-streams in a multi-tracking setup

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I needed to change a working Google Analytics setup in a site which was running with the **'Asynchronous Analytics' API** to include a new tracker from a new GA account/property. Google suggested using the new **'Universal Analytics' API**.

As I was not sure if there might be a **collision of names** when using both scripts together in the same page I followed the [instructions in the API documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#multipletrackers) on how to set up multiple trackers and switched the older Tracker to the 'Universal Analytics' API too.

This is the tracker code I used:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'mysite.org'); 
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-15', {'name': 'oldTracker'}); 
ga('oldTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

Now Google Analytics shows both trackers active and sending identical data. I can watch this in the GA Real-Time Reporting. Nevertheless the standard reports for the older tracker (last line in the code) stopped working. These stats are empty.

Any ideas how to repair this? Can this be caused by switching from Asynchronous to Universal Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [posting in the Google Group google-analytics-analyticsjs](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-analytics-analyticsjs/ZElmrDNllB0) from March 26th where 
Jim Wogulis, a Google developer, answered a similar question about migrating the tracker of a web property from Asynchronous to Universal Analytics, without recreating the property, with: *"We are currently working on the ability to support this kind of migration but it isn't available yet."*

So I changed my tracking code of these two web properties back to a mixture of old (Asynchronous) an new (Universal) and I see both working.